# Convergent sequence has one limit point

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to prove that if a sequence is convergent, it has exactly one limit point.

I have started proving this by contradiction, but can't seem to come to an equation that is obviously wrong. Please help.

Comment: What definition are you using for the limit point of the sequence?

Comment: d is a limit point if for $n \geq N$, $|a_n - d|\leq \epsilon$

Comment: Suppose two limits $l_1\ne l_2$ and pick $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: I have written out the equation in this way, but don't see how this leads to a contradiction

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\;|l_1-l_2|=\epsilon>0\;$ . Now:

$$\begin{cases}a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}l_1\implies\;\exists\,N_1\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>N_1\implies |a_n-l_1|<\frac\epsilon3\\{}\\a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}l_2\implies\;\exists\,N_2\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>N_2\implies |a_n-l_2|<\frac\epsilon3\end{cases}$$

So take $\;m>\max\{N_1,N_2\}\;$ , and then

$$\epsilon=|l_1-l_2|=|l_1-a_m+a_m-l_2|\le|l_1-a_m|+|l_2-a_m|<\frac23\epsilon...\text{contradiction.}$$

Comment: Why can we assume that the first line is valid?

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction, @user989 ...